# Django Tastypie error 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: postgresql, jsonp, put, tastypie

I want to update my table 'Dispatches' from my db which is in Postgresql ("SQL_ASCII")
But when I test, get the next error

Test

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"status":"4", "cancel_detail":"Cliente canceló"}' http://localhost:8000/api/taxi/dispatch_cancel_client/1047/?tk=308b3f13-15bf-4a45-a6be-7dfbcdb59cc3
```

Get this Error

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3
```

Can anyone help me to solution this issue ? 
Another thing that happens is when y send next code:

```
curl --dump-header - -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data '{"status":"4", "cancel_detail":"Cliente cancel\u00f3"}' http://localhost:8000/api/taxi/dispatch_cancel_client/1047/?tk=308b3f13-15bf-4a45-a6be-7dfbcdb59cc3
```

This is OK, but in the database save in the column "cancel_detail" -> "Cliente cancelÃ³"
and should be "Cliente canceló"